# Is it possible to link material but not image texture for different objects?

Tags: texturing, materials, linked-data

I have multiple objects and I would like to use the same material for all of them, but different image textures.

I can go and just manually edit all the materials to match each time I want to change it, but that can get tedious.

The objects also have linked mesh and UV data in this case.

Comment: Is every image a different file or are they part of a movie file?

Comment: perhaps, when several objects have similarities in their texture, use different material with different textures but the same node groups, so you don't have to recreate very similar node organisation in each material?

Comment: @joshsanfelici Every image is a different file.

Comment: @moonboots That would work but it's a bit tedious. I was wondering if there was a way to link the non-texture part so they automatically update for all objects.